# Sending email to yahoo and hotmail users?

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am using php and mysql.

Each time a user registers on my website, I use php mail() to send a single email for authentication.

Recently I found out that, a lot of Yahoo and Hotmail users have not activated their accounts. Let us say of 1000 users, only 200 are activated.

I am curious, and I try to register using my Hotmail account. To my surprise I didn't get the activation email.

Is my domain being blocked from sending email? How to solve this problem? I tested my others email account (my company and gmail), it works fine. I think only Yahoo and Hotmail give me problems!

Comment: how about posting your mailing codes? sometimes mail may be delayed. did you check your mail logs?

Comment: u mean my email header? But I think its not delay. I also include return-path to my bounce mail account. But my bounce mail account receive nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sire, Google is your friend.
In short, there is no simple answer to your question. Email delivery is not very trivial, especially since it does not depend on your programming entirely.

99% is your host fault. If your are VPSing, or on shared hosting - you can forget about it since you are inheriting reputation of other 300 people using the same server.

If you own your server, check your [IP reputation](https://www.senderscore.org) and then figure that you will need 2-3 months of flawless emailing to start getting through.

If you have 5K to blow a month, use [ReturnPath](http://www.returnpath.net) OR just someone like [CampaignMonitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com) or [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) ESPs to deliver your emails.

**DEBUG:** If you have root/shell access, try the following:

- "dig mx yahoo.com" from shell
- copy first or second authorized answer
- telnet (IP/domain) 25
- **manually** emulate SMTP conversation [like this](http://postmaster.aol.com/tools/telnet.html)
- Paste what the Yahoo mail server tells you here

P.S. If you are getting into spam folder, congrats! Typically your mail will be dropped at SMTP level, quietly. Worse even you will get deferred SMTP errors from Yahoo : that means they throttle you because they do not have enough data on your complaint ratios.

P.P.S. Setup DNS records to include SPF, and also push DKIM signing for your MTA. This will help greatly when you will try to prove your legitimacy.

P.P.P.S. Use http://www.senderbase.org/ to look up your IP first.

Good luck.

Comment: Should I contact my host? in my email content, i have 3 links, activate, company and delete account link. Is that considered spam content? (well, i dont think so, cuz I was follow other website email content)

Comment: Do you have a shared hosting, VPS or dedicated?

Comment: Use this site (http://www.senderbase.org/) to look up your domain/IP, see what the blacklists tell you

Comment: Added debug section on top, try that and post back

Comment: Ok, i am trying the debug now

Comment: Well, I am not sure why. But it seems like yahoo can went through now. Weird!! Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: Great! Don't forget during peak hours your emails will take awhile to get through.

Answer (score 1):

If me, I will register my custom domain to google apps, and will open an gmail account with own domain.

Then I will send email through google mail server. Its hard to goes into spam folder, unless your domain is in blacklist or some reasons.

Here is the hello world sample of sending email through google's mail server.

```
$user=$from="sender@yourdmain.com"
$to="receiver@email.com"
$passwd="sender@yourdmain.com's password"

require_once 'Mail.php';

$params = array(
'host'=> 'tls://smtp.gmail.com','port'=> 465,'auth'=> true,'debug'  => false,
'username' => $user,
'password' => $passwd
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', $params);
$smtp->send($to, array('From'=>$from,'To'=>$to), "Hello World!");
```

sorry, If you dont want to do like that.

Comment: People like you break the Internet!

Comment: Well, main point is to work properly and need to think for customer, isn't it? I don't think its bad idea to use google email server.

Comment: yes and no. If enough spammers use this hack, something worse in terms of "filtering" will get implemented. Example: email stamps. Do you want to pay to send emails? No? Well people that use tricks may as well cause this.

Comment: ah ok, you talking from the side from spammer. ok, absolutely true. but I still believe he and me is not spammer :D

Answer (score 0):

It's all about fighting spam...  You probably need to setup an sender policy framework records...  Hotmail uses SenderID

http://postmaster.msn.com/Guidelines.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/technologies/senderid/default.mspx
http://www.openspf.org/

Good luck!